# Is there a way to know what chrome process comes from chromedrive using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

As the question said i want to know if its possible to know what Chrome process comes from ChromeDrive using Python. The problem is that i don't have the code for the python script that is using the ChromeDrive. So is it possible to kill just the ChromeDrive Chrome with a independent script? Because i want to be able to use the normal chrome and not the ChromeDrive Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can use the psutil module to check the running chrome processes, kill the process having 'webdriver' in command-line argument.

```
from contextlib import suppress

import psutil
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072010/is-there-a-way-to-know-what-chrome-process-comes-from-chromedrive-using-python')

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name() == 'chrome.exe' and '--test-type=webdriver' in process.cmdline():
         with suppress(psutil.NoSuchProcess):
             process.kill()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import psutil
for process in psutil.process_iter ():
if process.name() == 'chrome.exe':
    Name = process.name () 
    ID = process.pid 
    print ("Process name =", Name ,",","Process ID =", ID)
```

Comment: Can you further explain your answer, please?